# Was TRIM support backported into the 2.6.32 kernel that is in 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, kernel, ssd, trim

I have found conflicting answers to this around the web, even a link to a launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/571476 which is kind of left hanging.

So I'm curious, was TRIM support backported into the 2.6.32 kernel that is in 10.04? Does anyone know for sure?

**Edit**
Although the above Launchpad Bug is relevant, it's this bug that is linked from the last comment on the above one that is most relevant: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/644694

In this, for Lucid update to 2.6.32.22 stable release there is listed under:
The following patches are in the 2.6.32.22 stable release:
   * sata_mv: fix broken DSM/TRIM support (v2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; only critical bug fixes are added to stable releases, not new features.  See [StableReleaseUpdates](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).  10.04 is quite old now, so you should upgrade to 12.04 if you want to stay with an LTS release, or 12.10 if you don't.

Comment: I'm running 12.10 - this is for someone who has a business reason to run 10.04 (for now) for compatibility, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: ...and I do ask, do you know this for *sure*, because if I dig around Google again like I did the other night, I can find sources that say it was in fact backported into the 2.6.32 kernel.

Comment: @JaysonRowe, actually it appears that the lucid kernel has ( and always did have ) discard support.